# How to Get a Language Switcher in Custom phtml File.?

Tags: magento2, custompage, language-switcher

I have a Custom Page, on that I had Hide the Header and Footer. But i need a Language Switcher in my custom Page. I had tried like this below on my Layout XML file,

```
<block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="Magento_Store::switch/languages.phtml"/>
```

My full Layout Xml File is below,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"layout="1column"xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="St_CustomMultiseller::css/customregister.css"/>
</head>
<body>  
  <referenceBlock name="header.content" remove="true" />
  <referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="true"/>
  <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" /> 
   <referenceBlock name="vendor_create_form" remove="true"/>
  <referenceBlock name="vendor.create">
       <action method="setTemplate">
             <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">St_CustomMultiseller::account/create.phtml </argument>       
       </action>
       <block class="\VendorsCustomRegister\Block\Account\Create\Vendor" name="new_vendor_create_form" template="St_CustomMultiseller::account/create/vendor-form.phtml"/>
       <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="Magento_Store::switch/languages.phtml"/>
  </referenceBlock>

</body>
```

But it not comes. Anyone help me to get the Language Switcher on my custom page.

Answer (score 0):

To show the element in your phtml file, you have to add the following code to your phtml file

```
<?php $block->getChildHtml('store_language');?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. i had done that already bro.

Answer (score 0):

I had get a Store Switcher by using the `<move>` tag to move the language switcher to my custom block and changed my Layout xml file like below,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"layout="1column"xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
<css src="St_CustomMultiseller::css/customregister.css"/>
</head>
<body>  
<referenceBlock name="header.content" remove="true" />
<move element="store_language" destination="vendor.create" />
<referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" /> 
<referenceBlock name="vendor_create_form" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="vendor.create">
   <action method="setTemplate">
         <argument name="template" 
 xsi:type="string">St_CustomMultiseller::account/create.phtml </argument>       
   </action>
   <block class="\VendorsCustomRegister\Block\Account\Create\Vendor" name="new_vendor_create_form" template="St_CustomMultiseller::account/create/vendor-form.phtml"/>

   </referenceBlock>
   </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly Put below code in .phtml file

[image]